exact definition of unevaluatedProperties in jsonschema
There is the unevaluatedProperties keyword in newer jsonschema drafts and I understand what the purpose of this is.
It was introduced because the "additionalProperties: false" idiom that disallows unknown properties makes schemas non-extendable: We cannot extend the schema without modifying it, putting it in an allOf construct will not work. For that there is now unevaluatedProperties.
The spec can be found here https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/json-schema-core#section-11.3.
But I want to understand the exact definition of unevaluatedProperties on a technical level. I cannot really make sense of the definition

Validation with "unevaluatedProperties" applies only to the child values of instance names that do not appear in the "properties", "patternProperties", "additionalProperties", or "unevaluatedProperties" annotation results that apply to the instance location being validated.

What does this mean?
Especially:

... applies only to the child values of instance names ...   How can instance names have child values?

instance names that .. do not appear in the [...] "additionalProperties" .... How can that be? additionalProperties does not list any names (contrary to properties or patternProperties which at least list a name pattern).


Maybe some example: What is the intended behavior of the following jsonschema?
{ 
  "anyOf": [
     true,
     "not": { "properties": { "a": true } }   // <<<< other lines below
  ], 
  "unevaluatedProperties": false  
}

Interesting JSON candidate instances are {},  { "a": 1 } { "b": 1 }
Variants of the above schema are with the "<<<<" line replaced with

"not": { "properties": { "a": false }
"not": { "additionalProperties": false }
"not": { "additionalProperties": true }

(I strongly suspect that the "not" construct is not really changing anything, but lets include it for fun. Or change it to a solitary if keyword.)
I am not asking what validators are responding, but what the correct behavior according to the schema spec is. With explanation please :-)

Prior to unevaluated* keywords, composition keywords had some difficulty with extensible schemas and composition.
Take these examples
allOf requires each subschema to pass validation. Any subschema in an allOf construct with additionalProperties: false defined would break validation for any adjacent subschema because no other properties are allowed other than those defined.
additionalProperties cannot see into other schemas: adjacent, parent, or child.
$schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
allOf:
- properties:
    name:
      type: string
- properties:
    age:
      type: number
  additionalProperties: false

# failing
name: john

#failing
name: john
age: 10

# passing
age: 10


This is a very common example and greatly misunderstood
We come back to this comment: additionalProperties cannot see into other schemas: adjacent, parent, or child.
In this case, the root of the schema defines allOf and additionalProperties: false.
A key understanding for JSON Schema is each schema resource is validated independently.
This example defines 3 unique schemas, the root, the first and second index in allOf. The root schema will prevent any undefined properties at the root. Thus, the allOf will always evaluate to false and this schema will never allow any passing instance.
additionalProperties: false
allOf:
- properties:
    name:
      type: string
- properties:
    age:
      type: number

# failing
name: john
age: 10

# failing
age: 10

# failing
name: john


We now have a solution that works with the expected behavior of many JSON Schema users. An inheritance-like pattern, although, not strictly inheritance as in a programming language.
unevaluatedProperties works in the way most people expected the combination of allOf and additionalProperties: false to work. It allows the validator to see into subschemas defined in a composition keyword. It only works in a one-way direction, child schemas from where the keyword is defined. It cannot see into adjacent or parent schemas.
$schema: https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/schema
unevaluatedProperties: false
allOf:
- properties:
    name:
      type: string
- properties:
    age:
      type: number

# passing
name: john

# passing
age: 10

# passing
name: john
age: 10

# failing
name: john
age: 10
month: January

Obviously, these are very basic examples, but hopefully it explains the behavior well enough where you can understand how to use it for more complex schemas.

Thanks for this answer, but I am aware of the way unevaluatedProperties works for the examples you mention. It is the exact definition I want to understand. Exactly where your language starts to get fuzzy :-)  ... the validator to *see* into subschemas ...  . It is the "see" into subschemas where it gets fuzzy and where I want the proper definition. See my examples: They leave questions: How "properties" inside a "not" or an "if" affect the unevaluatedProperties? Does the truth value of the validation (e.g. inside the "not" or an "if") affect unevaluatedProperties? This is unclear for me.

Thanks for using yaml, it is way more readable than json.

Regarding the explanation of this schema
{ 
  "anyOf": [
     true,
     {"not": { "properties": { "a": true } } }  // <<<< other lines below
  ], 
  "unevaluatedProperties": false  
}


any non-empty object instance will fail because there no properties defined in the subschemas.
The not will evaluate true if you were to create an instance such as below but because it's not allowed, the schema evaluation would be false.
a: true

otherwise, all other types of instances will pass successfully because a true schema in the anyOf, will allow any other instance to pass.
# passing
1

# passing
0.1

# passing
true

# passing
false

# passing
[]

# passing
{}

# failing
{ "test": 1}


EDIT:

But you missed the most interesting case { "a": 1 } :-). That should pass. Yes?!

a: 1 is a valid instance because a true schema is unconstrained in JSON Schema. true means any schema is valid, including the hypothetical a: 1. But, because you are using a not keyword, the inverse is returned, false, thus the schema fails.
# failing
a: 1


And what happens if I change {"a": true} in the schema to {"a": "false"}. I guess it will also pass, yes?! But why?

This one is interesting because a: false is a valid instance for the anyOf: [true] schema but, the instance fails because unevaluatedProperties: false prevents any object instance with a property defined because there are no properties defined in the root or any child schema that would allow successful validation.
anyOf:
- true,  // passes here
- not: // fails here because `not` returns the inverse of the subschema validation (true)
    properties:
      a: true //  passes here
unevaluatedProperties: false // fails here because no `properties` or `patternProperties` definition is defined in the root or any child schema to allow `a`

# failing
a: false



Anyway, I would still like to understand where this is written in the standard.

There are multiple considerations which are touching many parts of the specification.
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-4.3.1
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-4.3.2
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-7.5
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-7.6
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-10.2.1.2
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-11
https://json-schema.org/draft/2020-12/draft-bhutton-json-schema-01#section-11.3

Thanks, But you missed the most interesting case { "a": 1 } :-). That should pass. Yes?! And what happens if I change {"a": true} in the schema to {"a": "false"}. I guess it will also pass, yes?! But why?
Anyway, I would still like to understand where this is written in the standard.

.... Regarding your answer: There are no "properties" defined in the subschemas. This is not true. In the adjacent schemas the property "a" is defined: inside the "not" inside of "anyOf". Both "not" and "anyOf" are applied in-place. And the "unevaluatedProperties" should be able to "see" through the in-place applied stuff. No ? :-) You maybe see, why I have some difficulty with this "see through" wording :-)....

... The stuff in the anyOf has no direct influence on the outcome of the validation. No matter what validation result the "not" has, it does not matter. Also it does not matter that there is a "not". But it must influence the behavior of "unevaluatedProperties", right? If there is a property defined in such a "dead" section of the schema, it affects unevaluatedProperties. But how ? And where the standard says this?

updated the answer with more information

btw, you can join the Slack https://join.slack.com/t/json-schema/shared_invite/zt-1rptj13ch-ZygpGVq7jUxQYpct0vwsGQ or join github discussions https://github.com/orgs/json-schema-org/discussions if you want to interact with more JSON Schema members.

I think you're right that the passage you quoted doesn't make sense and needs to be rewritten. So, instead of trying to make it make sense, I'm going to ignore what it says and just describe how unevaluatedProperties is intended to work.
unevaluatedProperties works by using annotations collected by evaluating the properties, patternProperties, and additionalProperties keywords. Each of these keywords collects the property names that they successfully evaluate.
{
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "type": "number" },
  },
  "patternProperties": {
    "^b": { "type": "boolean" }
  },
  "unevaluatedProperties": false
}

Given the instance { "foo": 42, "bar": false, "baz": null }, properties contributes "foo" and patternProperties contributes "bar". That makes the set of evaluated properties, "foo", "bar". unevaluatedProperties then uses that set to determine that "baz" is unevaluated and validates it against the false schema making the instance fail validation.
Unlike additionalProperties, the set of evaluated properties that's constructed is keyed off of the instance location being evaluated rather than the instance location and the schema location.
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "a": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "apple": true
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "apricot": true
          }
        },
      ],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    },
    "b": {
      "type": "object",
      "allOf": [
        {
          "properties": {
            "banana": true
          }
        },
        {
          "properties": {
            "blueberry": true
          }
        },
      ],
      "unevaluatedProperties": false
    }
  }
}

Here, we have three locations that define objects that the validator will collect evaluated properties for.

# -- a, b
#/a -- apple, apricot
#/b -- banana, blueberry

Notice that the nesting of the schemas doesn't matter because the schema nesting doesn't effect the location being evaluated.
The set of properties used for additionalProperties also keys off of the schema location, which is why the schema nesting matters for additionalProperties and not unevaluatedProperties.

#, # -- a, b
#/a, #/properties/a --
#/a, #/properties/a/allOf/0 -- apple
#/a, #/properties/a/allOf/1 -- apricot
#/b, #/properties/b --
#/b, #/properties/b/allOf/0 -- banana
#/b, #/properties/b/allOf/1 -- blueberry

There's one more complication to consider. When a schema fails validation, any properties it would otherwise contribute to the set of evaluated properties gets dropped.
{
  "type": "object",
  "anyOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "number" }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "number", "minimum": 0 },
        "bar": { "type": "boolean" }
      }
    }
  ],
  "unevaluatedProperties": false
}

Consider the instance { "foo": -1, "bar": null }. In /anyOf/1, "bar" is successfully evaluated and "foo" is not. Because the schema as a whole fails, its evaluated properties get dropped. So, "bar" is considered unevaluated and the validation fails.
An interesting consequence of this is that anything in not never ends up getting collected because the failed validation drops anything that it would have contributed.
{
  "not": {
    "not": {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { "type": "number" }
      }
    }
  },
  "unevaluatedProperties": false
}

You would think that double negation is a no-op, but it actually results in dropping all collected properties. So, { "foo": 42 } will pass the not, but will fail unevaluatedProperties and the validation will fail. Only the empty object will pass this schema.
